# How long will a pokemon stay in one location

Tags: pokemon-go

4 days ago I caught a Dratini in an alley at midnight. Today I found another Dratini in the same spot at the same time. I'm wondering if this is just dumb luck or if it actually stays there. I'm going to the same spot ,tomorrow, to see if it will be there again.

Is there a guarantee if it will be there? How long will a Pokemon stay in the same location?

Comment: Your going to go to somewhere to catch a Pokémon. Nice. And the question? It doesn't seem like your asking one, really.

Comment: @Alex, if you can tell there is a question (I.e. it's in the actual title), dont hesitate to edit it into the question. Saves potential false close votes.

Comment: @Timelord64 I couldn't find a question before. Until it was edited. He said he found two Pokémon on one area and he it going to look again tomorrow. That's not a question to me. I guess I didn't read the title carefully enough.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot catch the same Pokémon twice. You can only catch another one of the same kind, which happened in your case.

If you catch a Pokémon it is gone for you, since you have it in your bags now. Going back to that place won't spawn the same Pokémon again, unless you're on a different account and within a few minutes. After 4 days it was definitely a different Dratini, especially if you already caught the other one.

Comment: Not agree with you as my friend got ratata, spraow and 2 more pokemon atleast 6th times.

Comment: You can collect more Pokémon of the same kind, yes. But you cannot catch the very same Pokémon again once you caught it.

Comment: he means it's a different Dratini.

Comment: Today i see Clefairy in my "Nearby Monster" list. Should i search it?

Comment: if you want to catch it, yes.

Comment: @Leothelion, all incredibly common Pokemon. Your friend simply ean into differant instances of the pokemon, not the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a chance every hour at the same minute that a Pokékom spawns at a given point. But this Pokémon can be of any type. (But some types have higher rates in different locations). So for your Dratini it is possible to spawn every hour at minute XX and so it will also spawn after 24 hours at minute XX. Maybe you are lucky to find two times the same Monster or it's a spot where only Dratinis have a spawn chance.

Answer (score -1):

Theres a good chance. Pokemon stay around the same area so while you cant calculate it up 2 "hey every 24 hrs im running here for a dratini" but where you find a pokemon you like visit there frquently they stay in the same area. Cheers hope that helps